# How to set a custom domain for a specific route in netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, netlify, vercel

I have a react app and a node api, I'm planning to host the react app on netlify and I want my users to be able set custom domains, the route can have other routes too, for example `example.com/route1/97/route2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a routing library like React Router, and then to get Netlify to let you use it, define this in your `_redirects` file:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question Luke, im not talking about react router, im talking about how to set a custom domain for a specific route, automaticlly just like shopify do when you create a store you can set a custom domain.

Comment: What do you mean by custom domain? You want users to be able to host your app on their URLs? That's not something Netlify is really for

Comment: In your example, `example.com/route1/97/route2` can be done with react router

Comment: Hey Luke thanks for commanting back :) i appreciate it,  yes im talking about how my users can host my app on their URL, and whats the the alternatives that make me able to achieve something like that is there a free service ?

Comment: I mean you could somehow try and do it via netlify sure, and you could probably get it so that users can have their own sub-folders in your site, but if you're planning on running  your own hosting service then you have a lot of googling to do, its way off topic for here